# devise: changing namespace changes the "current_user" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have following route which allow me to call `current_user` function inside Rails controller
I'm using `gem 'devise-jwt', '~> 0.6.0'`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
end
```

When I change Route to following, I'm no longer able to call `current_user` function

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_for :accounts
    end
  end
end
```

The error comes like following:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<API::V1::UsersController:0x00007f9fb7c64ec8> Did you mean? current_api_v1_user
```

I need to use same `current_user` method after putting Devise inside namespace

Answer (score 0):

The gem Devise Token Auth gives you the ability to use the current_user functionality of devise on API requests.

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth